# why connection always gets refused?

Tags: python, rpyc

I am trying to connect machine using the RPyC but it always says that connection refused.

I did on the python shell

```
import rpyc
rpyc.connect("hostname", port)
```

but it says connection refused. checked the firewall for the port. firewall allow this port.

Comment: Is the server running?

Comment: Yes.it is running. why it says connection refused almost for evey machine for which I am trying.

Comment: `every machine` you mean servers or clients. If a server process is running on `hostname` then probably `port` is blocked by a firewall or you are using the wrong port number. Even `hostname` is not reachable on the network.

Comment: or perhaps you have a variable named `hostname` but you accidentally pass the string `"hostname"` instead of the value of the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the exact same versions of both python and rpyc on client and server !

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are not runnin the server side for rpyc
you need to donwload the source code for rpyc from here

https://github.com/tomerfiliba-org/rpyc/releases

then run:

python bin/rpyc_classic.py

where bin is in the source code folder

Once you have that running, you should be able to run the python code without any issues

I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

default server binds to localhost, but the client needs to have hostname 'None' to do this correctly:

```
rpyc.connect(None, port)
```